# getting the projected 2D "frame" of a SCNNode

Tags: io, uikit, scenekit, scnnode

I'm building a paged scrollview for SceneKit, where i have a bunch of nodes under a main `contentNode` as seen below.

My problem is trying to figure out the width of the node - in 2D coordinates - so i can calculate the amount of padding as seen below.

**Current (failed) plan**

- projecting one of the nodes' `boundingBox`. Got an unreasonably large value there for width.
- calculate amount of horizontal padding by subtracting the width of my `SCNSceneView` by the width of one of the nodes. All nodes are the same width and height.
- Use half of that value so the objects to the left and right "peek" in a bit.
- Unproject that value so i can apply the spacing.

So i'm stumped at the crazy values for the bounding box if anyone understands my error.

[image]

Comment: Some code might be useful. I use CALayer and addSublayer which you give a frame, layer.frame = frameOne, etc. frameOne is a CGRect which you can give position and width and height comparative to the layer.frame